# How to customize group label in Angular UI-Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-select

In Angular ui-select ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)), how can I customize group label?

[image]

As shown in the image, the list is grouped by country, how can I customize the group label so to make it larger then the selection items?

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e2yMJI5LpyjghWlYG2Kr?p=preview)

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices group-by="'country'" repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
  <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  <small>
    email: {{person.email}}
    age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </small>
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The example is modified from the official example [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-groupby.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am guessing you would like to customize the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply targeted the CSS class that was bound to the group by label as follow:

```
.ui-select-choices-group-label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

You can see the updated [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XcY7KHYcinH6aI9Ubgwb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

We had similar need, but we did not want to change this style for all groups.

So here is the solution we found:

Add class `biggerGroup` to your `ui-select-choices` like in this example:

```
<ui-select-choices class="biggerGroup" group-by="'country'" repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
```

Add this in your .css file:

```
.biggerGroup > .ui-select-choices-group > .ui-select-choices-group-label {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Now, if you need to change group styling in your selection, just add this `biggerGroup` class and voila.

I hope it may help someone.